# What's the maximum grid column count using LESS variables?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, less

I wonder, how many (max number) columns could possibly be set in variables.less? 
And If someone can tell me how does bootstrap grid mixins work, would be great. I mean, how can be created different count of .col-[size]-[count] classes after LESS is compiled, without loops (no loops in LESS, right?)

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- (basic customisation) use the customizer online http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables
- (advanced customisation) edit variables.less inside your project and recompile

Let's talk about the manual customization.

You can change the number of grids in `variables.less`

```
//== Grid system
//
//## Define your custom responsive grid.

//** Number of columns in the grid.
@grid-columns:              12;
//** Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.
@grid-gutter-width:         30px;
```

There is not a max number. The only thing to take care is that you have the gutter width so for example if you double the columns (24 instead of 12) it makes sense to have the gutter half size (15px instead of 30px)

You have also access to media-queries variables and you can set for example a bigger screen size here:

```
//== Media queries breakpoints
//
//## Define the breakpoints at which your layout will change, adapting to different screen sizes.

// Extra small screen / phone
//** Deprecated `@screen-xs` as of v3.0.1
@screen-xs:                  480px;
//** Deprecated `@screen-xs-min` as of v3.2.0
@screen-xs-min:              @screen-xs;
//** Deprecated `@screen-phone` as of v3.0.1
@screen-phone:               @screen-xs-min;

...

// Large screen / wide desktop
//** Deprecated `@screen-lg` as of v3.0.1
@screen-lg:                  1200px;
@screen-lg-min:              @screen-lg;
//** Deprecated `@screen-lg-desktop` as of v3.0.1
@screen-lg-desktop:          @screen-lg-min;

// Xtra-Large screen / wide desktop
//** Deprecated `@screen-lg` as of v3.0.1
@screen-xl:                  1600px;
@screen-xl-min:              @screen-xl;
//** Deprecated `@screen-xl-desktop` as of v3.0.1
@screen-xl-desktop:          @screen-xl-min;

// So media queries don't overlap when required, provide a maximum
@screen-xs-max:              (@screen-sm-min - 1);
@screen-sm-max:              (@screen-md-min - 1);
@screen-md-max:              (@screen-lg-min - 1);
@screen-lg-max:              (@screen-xl-min - 1);
```

Then you have to set also the `.container` size that is always your viewport size minus 2 times the gutter size (left side and right side of the page).
With the standard 30px gutter width this number will be 60px.
So for example the `.container` for the extra-large viewport that we created (1600px width) will be 1600px - 60px = 1540px.

```
//== Container sizes
//
//## Define the maximum width of `.container` for different screen sizes.

...

// Large screen / wide desktop
@container-large-desktop:      ((1140px + @grid-gutter-width));
//** For `@screen-lg-min` and up.
@container-lg:                 @container-large-desktop;

// Extra-Large screen / wide desktop
@container-xtra-large:      ((1540px + @grid-gutter-width));
//** For `@screen-xl-min` and up.
@container-xl:                 @container-xtra-large;
```

The last step is to generate the new grid for this new xtra-large viewport that we just set so you need to edit the `grids.less`

```
//
// Grid system
// --------------------------------------------------


// Container widths
//
// Set the container width, and override it for fixed navbars in media queries.

.container {
  .container-fixed();

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    width: @container-sm;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    width: @container-md;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-xl-min) {
    width: @container-xl;
  }
}

....

// Large grid
//
// Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the large desktop device range.

@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
  .make-grid(lg);
}

// Xtra-Large grid
//
// Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the large desktop device range.

@media (min-width: @screen-xl-min) {
  .make-grid(xl);
}
```